# Run automatically generated scripts parallel in sql server

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am creating a process that automates testing the consistency in database tables across servers.
I have a test_master table which contains following columns:

```
test_id, test_name, test_status
```

and Job_master table which contains  following columns:

```
jid, test_id, job_name, job_type, job_path, job_status, 
server_ip, db, error_description, op_table,  test_table,
copy_status, check_status
```

There can be multiple jobs for a particular test. The jobs are logical jobs (and not sql agent jobs), they can be script, procedure or ssis package.
So I have made an ssis package :

[image]

In Pre-execute, it takes up tests which aren't done yet.

Each Job runs and writes the name of live table into op_table field

In post-execute, the live tables are getting copied to a test database environment and table name is put into test_table.. and testing will be performed there only.

Here the jobs are running in a loop... Is there a way to let the jobs run in parallel because they are independent of each other.... 
Can I write an sql procedure for this inside of this loop or is there any other way I can do this.. 
Any new ideas are welcome...
Thank you very much.. :)

Comment: Given the design, I don't see a way in which you can run the jobs in parallel. But you can introduce some sort of parallelism by logically diving the for-each loop. What I am suggesting is to have more than one for-each loop based on some criteria. Also, you could try multiple For loops instead of the for-each loop.

Comment: Is there another way, say by an sql script by which I can achieve this parallelism?

Comment: You could look into a Script task that performs the jobs asynchronously.   It would completely replace your entire for-each loop.

Comment: Encapsulate the logic inside your ForEach Loop Container into a sub packages. Invoke that package out of process (asynchronously) and you'll get parallelism. However, your update Test status and Post-exec steps may fire while teh packages are running, since it'll be disconnected. That's likely not the desired behaviour.

Comment: I am not getting proper keywords to search this.. So here's the thing.. what if I enclose the job instructions together in one exec(@sql)? where @sql will contain queries ';' separated. Will Sql server consider it independent and exec every instruction separately?

Answer (score 0):

*Very roughly*, I would put the approach as below:

- **SQL bits**

Wrap whatever SQL code is part of "job" into a stored proc. Inside this proc, populate a variable which takes care of the SQL bit and execute it using dynamic SQL. Update the job status in the same proc and take help of `TRY-CATCH-THROW` construct.

- **Packages**

Populate the name of packages in an SSIS string variable in delimited fashion(or have an object variable, whatever suits you). Then, in a script task, iterate through the list of packages and fire them using `dtExec` command. To update the job status, it's best to have the update of job status taken care by the invoked packages. If that is not an option, use `Try-catch` construct, update the job statuses according. [This](http://benefic.net/run-ssis-child-packages-with-script-task/) is a helpful link.

Do a check on the `job_type` variable on top of the SSIS package(using precedence constraint) and route them into the correct 'block'.